# Find general equation from 2 polar answers

Tags: polar-coordinates

There is $z^n = x+yi$ and $n$ natural
$z_1$ and $z_2$ are 2 answers of the equation. $z_1$'s angle is the smallest and $z_2$'s angle is the biggest.
$z_1 = \sqrt[4]{2}×e^{i \pi/12}$
$z_2 = \sqrt[4]{2}×e^{i 7 \pi /4 }$

Find $ n,x,y $

How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle between $z_1$ and $z_2$ is $\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{3}$ radians, If two neighboring roots of a number differ by $\frac16$ of a circle, they must be $6$th roots. Raising $z_1$ to the sixth power, we obtain $z_1^6 = 2^{3/2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$, or $2^{3/2}i$. Note that the sixth power of $z_2$ is the same.

Thus, it appears that $n=6$, $x=0$, and $y=2\sqrt{2}$

Does that make sense?

Comment: Perfectly! That really helped

Comment: Oh, that's nice and clean. +1

Comment: How did you find The angle between z1  and z2 ? How come it's 1/6?

Comment: Well, $z_1$ is $\frac{\pi}{12}$ radians above the positive real axis, and $z_2$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians below it. I added those two fractions to get the angle between the two. Drawing a picture might help if you don't see it.

Comment: Knowing that $\pi/3$ is one sixth of a circle is just a matter of knowing how radians work.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.** Take a look at the difference in arguments (what the original question calls the angle of the root):

$$
\frac{7\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{5\pi}{3}
$$

The fundamental difference in arguments between the $n$ roots must be $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ (do you see why?); at the same time, $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ must also be an integer multiple of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ (again, do you see why?).

At the same time, $\frac{2\pi}{n} > 2\pi-\frac{7\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}$; otherwise, $z_2$ would not be the root with the highest argument.

What does this permit you to say about the value of $n$?  Then raise $z_1$ and $z_2$ to this $n$th power, and see what you obtain.  That will be $x+yi$.